If $h_k\to h$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n$ then $(h_k\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon_k})\to h$ in$L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
Let $(h_k)_{k\in \mathbb{R}^n}\subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ converge to some $h$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $(\varphi_{\varepsilon_ k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be the standard mollification sequence. I want to show
$$(h_k\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon_k})\to h \text{ in }L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
We estimate
$$\|(h_k\ast \varphi_{\varepsilon_k})-h\|_{L^2}^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h_k(x-y) \varphi_{\varepsilon_k}(y)-h(x)|^2dy dx$$
How can I proceed if I don't have uniform continuity of $h$?

Here, you need the result that $h$ can be approximated by $h_k$ and every $h_k$ can be approximated by continuous functions. Did you already cover the latter result?

Can you do it if $h_k=h$ for all $k$?
